# Which voltage does the Power-On/Status and the HDD activity LED connectors of a motherboard deliver?

Tags: motherboard, led, wiring

The case I want to use does not have an option to connect the power or HDD activity LED. Therefore I would like to use some 3V LEDs I already own.

However, since they are only for 3V, I would like to know which voltage does the power on/status and the HDD activity LED connector deliver and if I can use them.

The motherboard in question is a [Gigabyte GA-Z68XP-UD3-iSSD](http://www.gigabyte.eu/products/product-page.aspx?pid=3896#ov), but the manual does not provide any information about this topic.

Comment: Do you have a multimeter? Plug it in and see what the DC voltage is directly. They can be had pretty cheaply. It'll help to have a normal load on the circuit; plug a standard case LED into there at the same time and put the multimeter in parallel.

Comment: @Chris Smith: No, I'm sorry I have no multimeter - yet. But I buy one with the next PC ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing I could find that mentioned a voltage was [here](http://www.directron.com/ledred.html) and it specified 3.3V

Comment: Thanks. A friend of mine just sent me this link and they say it would be 6V? http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/105629-12-power-voltage

Comment: This one says 3.3V http://www.overclock.net/computer-peripherals/717451-power-led-hdd-light-voltage-answer.html I guess the worst that will happen is your LED will go pop it won't kill the PC

Comment: Poor mens test then? If it smells = Does not work. JK, I will test it. Thanks for the fast answer!

Comment: Good luck with it.